# Javascript - How to filter but first checks if a state variable does not contain a certain value?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I have all my items in my original array called `items` and have a state that holds all of the filtered data:

```js
const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState(items);
```

I have states for my filters as such:

```js
const [filteredUser, setFilteredUser] = useState("");
const [filteredType, setFilteredType] = useState("");
const [filteredVariety, setFilteredVariety] = useState("");
```

This states are updated from `<HTMLSelect />` components as such:

```js
const handleUserSelect = (e) => {
    setFilteredUser(e.currentTarget.value);
}
// and so on...

<HTMLSelect onChange={handleUserSelect} />
<HTMLSelect onChange={handleTypeSelect} />
<HTMLSelect onChange={handleVarietySelect} />
```

Then I have a button that apply the filters to my data `items`:

```js
const handleApplyFilters = () => {
    setFilteredItems(
        items.filter(obj => (
            obj.user === filteredUser;
            obj.type === filteredType;
            obj.variety === filteredVariety;
        ))
    )
}

<Button onClick={handleApplyFilters}>Apply Filters</Button>
```

However, the problem is that, if I want to filter ONLY the `user` for example. So I want the filter to only filter out a certain user. How can I modify my `handleApplyFilters()` function so that if only the `filteredUser` is selected, then it won't filter `obj.type === ""` (as `filteredType` in this case would be `""` as nothing is being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition so that filters that are equal to an empty string (`''`) would be evaluated to `true` and would skip the equality check to the the `obj` properties.

For example the expression

```
filteredType === '' || obj.type === filteredType
```

would be truthy if `filteredType` is an empty string.

Code:

```
const handleApplyFilters = () => {
  setFilteredItems(
    items.filter(obj => (
      (filteredUser === '' || obj.user === filteredUser) &&
      (filteredType === '' || obj.type === filteredType) &&
      (filteredVariety === '' || obj.variety === filteredVariety)
    ))
  )
}
```

You can shorten the expression a bit by using `!` since `!''` is `true`:

```
const handleApplyFilters = () => {
  setFilteredItems(
    items.filter(obj => (
      (!filteredUser || obj.user === filteredUser) &&
      (!filteredType || obj.type === filteredType) &&
      (!filteredVariety || obj.variety === filteredVariety)
    ))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can reset `filteredType` and `filterVariety` states in `handleUserSelect` (whenever your user filter gets applied).

```
const handleUserSelect = (e) => {
    setFilteredUser(e.currentTarget.value);
    if(e.currentTarget.value) {
       setFilteredType("")
       setFilteredVariety("")
    }
}
```

Your filter application function also needs to be modified

```
const handleApplyFilters = () => {
    setFilteredItems(
        items.filter(obj => (
            (!filteredUser || obj.user === filteredUser) &&
            (!filteredType || obj.type === filteredType) &&
            (!filteredVariety || obj.variety === filteredVariety)
        ))
    )
}
```

Along with that, you also need to disable type and variety filters to prevent them get reselected.

*Note that I don't see your `HTMLSelect` component, so I'd assume `HTMLSelect` has a `disabled` prop.*

```
<HTMLSelect onChange={handleTypeSelect} disabled={filteredUser}/>
<HTMLSelect onChange={handleVarietySelect} disabled={filteredUser}/>
```